# Displaying content with functions does not work properly

Tags: php, arrays, class, fetch

**First of all: I know this is a very messy code and not the proper way to do this. But its first attempt to write a class and functions..**

**What i want it to do:** Output all rows in the "articles" table, in a div (div "repeated"for each row again) and sort it by id and date. Later on i want to filter it by page id.

**What it does:** Gives output of only 1 row, other rows are not displayed..

I hope my explanation makes sense..

This is what my "articles" table looks like right now:

|id|  |page_id|  |title|   |content|  |date|  |position|

Title is in plain text, content in html which comes from a WYSIWYG editor in the adminpanel and date is DD-MM-YYYY.

This is what my "class" looks like:

```
    include_once('./includes/config.php');
class Content {


public $id;
public $page_id;
public $title;
public $content;
public $position;



var $conn;

function Content()
        {
                $this->conn = mysql_connect(Config::DB_HOST, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASS);
                mysql_select_db(Config::DB_NAME, $this->conn);
        }


function get_content_articles()
{
    $sql = "SELECT id, page_id, title, content, date, position FROM articles ORDER BY id, position";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);

                if ( !$result )
                        return false;
    $fetch_all = array();

    while($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    $fetch_all[] = $article;

return $fetch_all;
}


public function display_content() {
    $this->article = $this->get_content_articles();
    foreach ( $this->article as $article)   

    $content = '<div class="blok">
        <h2>[id:'.$article['id'].']
        </br>
        [title: '.$article['title'].']</h2>
        </br>
        [content: '.$article['content'].']
        </br>
        [date: '.$article['date'].']
    </div>';

    return $content;
  }
}
```

This is how i use it:

```
$content = new Content();
```

echo $content->display_content();

Test page here: http://thepiratehenk.nl/pgwe/testcontent.php

Does someone have a suggestion on how to fix this? (Excuse me for my bad english and messy question, i hope it all makes sense.)

---

Ok, thanks for the answers so far. I know i should'nt use mysql_ functions in classes.. But its the only way i understand the most at this moment.

I changed the display_content() function to this:

```
    public function display_content() {
    $this->article = $this->get_content_articles();
    foreach ( $this->article as $article)   
    $content = "";
    $content .= '<div class="blok">
        <h2>[id:'.$article['id'].']
        </br>
        [title: '.$article['title'].']</h2>
        </br>
        [content: '.$article['content'].']
        </br>
        [date: '.$article['date'].']
    </div>';

    return $content;
  }
}
```

Is this the way you meant it to be? Anyway, the result doesnt change..

Comment: have you verified how many rows your query returns?

Comment: You need to concatentate each result onto `$content` - you're currently over-writing it each time you run through your `foreach` loop. Try ` $content .= ....` instead.

Comment: _But its first attempt to write a class and functions.._ .. then do start avoiding the usage of [mysql_*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions ..

Comment: Since it works properly now, are there other things that I can improve?

Comment: Use mysqli (or PDO) instead of mysql. The most code is okay now.

Comment: I also plan to start using it, but I want to have more knowledge about it first

Comment: I've just heard that there exists some site which is called PHP documentation... http://php.net/mysqli

Comment: Yes.. I do know the existence of the PHP documentation, but i am not ready for using it yet, since i do not even master php basic at the moment.

Comment: I have one last question: How do i filter the page_id by using $_GET['page'] with ?page=id.. Where do i put it in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the right way and what @bwoebi suggested:

```
    public function display_content() {
    $this->article = $this->get_content_articles();
    $content = "";
    foreach ( $this->article as $article)  { 

     $content .= '<div class="blok">
        <h2>[id:'.$article['id'].']
        </br>
        [title: '.$article['title'].']</h2>
        </br>
        [content: '.$article['content'].']
        </br>
        [date: '.$article['date'].']
      </div>';
     }
        return $content;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$content = '<div class="blok">...';
```

You are reassigning the variable `$content` with the value of the entry in every iteration of your foreach loop. So `$content` will only contain the last entry.

Use the appending operator `.=`.

```
$content .= '<div class="blok">...';
```

**EDIT**: As said in the comment by @JoseAreas, you should write before entering your loop:

```
$content = "";
```

to avoid some notice.

Comment: first, define it as blank before the loop, to avoid warnings.